# Swift 4: intermittent duplication of NSNotifcationCenter notifications

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am working on a Swift 4 app that uses a private CocoaPod.  The pod controls the camera, and when a user takes a photo they like, it saves the photo to a local file and uses `NSNotificationCenter` to signal the main app that there's a photo ready to be uploaded to our backend.

Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes the notifications get doubled, tripled, or more. It's unpredictable, but I've done some extensive logging and found that the pod can `post()` one notification to `NotificationCenter` and the observer can receive multiple identical notifications.  So the duplication of notifications seems to be happening inside of `NotificationCenter`.  I have ensured that only one observer exists for the specified notification.

The frustrating thing is that this only occurs about 5%-10% of the time, and I cannot figure out if there are any aggravating factors.  I was wondering if anyone has experience with this sort of issue, and whether you have any advice for workarounds.

Comment: When do you do `addObserver()` and when do you do `removeObserver()`? My guess is that sometimes, `addObserver()` is called many times, and that's why it gets called multiples times for a single notification.

Comment: @Larme I've tried a few different things with regard to this, and none have solved it.  The current setup is that I created a module with a singleton, and a function to add the observer.  So in my MainViewController's `viewDidLoad()`, I call my `addObserver()` function on the singleton, and that's it.  It's not being called anywhere else.